# Related Entries Relationships

Tags: templating, craft3

I am building a site where I have users, companies and content.

Currently my users are standard Craft users, and my companies and content are entries within a channel.

I have a field in my content called company name which is an asset field and lets me create a relationship between a piece of content and a company and now I want to create a comaopny page that lists all content "owned" by that company.

I have the below as a starting point which is listing all of my content but any help on what I'd need to do to tweak it so that it only displays content where company name is equal to the entry title (which is the company name)? Hopefully that makes some kind of sense!

Many thanks in advance!

```
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries()
    .companyName(':notempty:')
    .all() %}

{% if relatedEntries|length %}
    <ul>
        {% for rel in relatedEntries %}
            <li><a href="{{ rel.url }}">{{ rel.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So, you have a 'companies' channel and a 'content' channel? How have you related the two channels?

Comment: I have a field type (entries) that I use in my 'content' and choose the relevant company. As I say the above returns all content that has the company field filled out I just need to add logic that says only show those where companyName = entry.title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do:

```
{# Get segment 2 from the URL #}
{% set company = craft.app.request.getSegment(2) %}

{# Get content where myCompanyField matches segment 2 #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection').myCompanyField(company).all() %}
```

But I need to know more about the structure of your content.